# Can I return a file from the google drive API without first writing it to my server? (php)

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I currently have a script which loops through a google drive folder and does various things, one of which is to sync files uploaded/updated on gdrive with the files on the server. The script decides it wants a file, and uses the following function to write it to the server:

```
function get_file($file, $service, $docroot, $area){

    $errorthrown = false;
    try {
      $getFile = $service->files->get($file->id, array('alt' => 'media'));
      $content = $getFile->getBody()->getContents();
      $handle = fopen($docroot.'file/'.$area.'/'.$file->name,"w");
      fwrite($handle, $content);
      fclose($handle);          
    } catch (\Throwable $e) {
        print "The Google Drive API threw an error, but dont worry, we'll come back for this.";
        return "error";
    }
}
```

Now I would like to offer a file manager on the server which allows users to pick files, including those on the server and those which aren't. Is there a way of forcing the download of files returned from the google drive API, without first fwrite()ing?, for example using readfile() or fpassthru()?

I have tried various things with readfile() but from google drive I have the file contents, but no path to the file itself.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: of course, you don't need to save the `$content` var on a file, simply echo the var on output, with proper http headers

Comment: Brilliant Pierre!